# Store TF model weights in CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to adapt this [CNN built for MNIST](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~qi/deeplearning/code/cnnMNIST.py) for CIFAR10. I've modified the structure to accomodate the size of CIFAR images (32x32). The model trains on my GPU but whenever I run the evaluation function for test data (`test_eval`), I get an out of memory error for the first convolution (`hconv1`)-

```
 ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10000,32,32,32]
     [[Node: Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Reshape, W_conv1/read/_79)]]
```

Now I tried running the same code on my CPU (by using `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""`) and the `test_eval` function runs successfully. So I thought maybe if I explicitly store only my weight variables on my CPU it might work. So I modified the `weight_variable` function from  -

```
def weight_variable(self, shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
```

to

```
def weight_variable(self, shape):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        initial = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))            
    return initial
```

Yet I am still getting an OOM error when I run the `test_eval` function. Does the above code actually store the variable in CPU? How do I solve this?

My GPU is GeForce GTX 950M, 2GB. Also, the code for MNIST CNN that I posted above was adapted from [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py)

Answer (score 0):

Memory is usually taken up by activations. For instance your first conv layer has 3.2K in weights, but 32x28x28x10000x4 = 1.003GB in activations. This is followed by broadcasting add, so you need more than 2GB RAM to go through first layer. See [this](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/notebooks/blob/master/mnist-memory.ipynb) for an example of profiling memory